# Saving text and inserting it after a specified variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

there's a site with lots of comments.

```
code1
<p>hello ernie</p>
<p>this is mark</p>
<p>hello ben</p>
<p>this is ernie</p>
<p>hello mark</p>
<p>this is ben</p>
```

Now I want to collect all comments containing 'hello' and insert the phrases with hello after all comments.

```
$("p:contains('hello')").insertAfter($("#comments"));
```

'hello' is taken from the comments and inserted after the comments.

```
code2
<p>this is mark</p>
<p>this is ernie</p>
<p>this is ben</p>
```

```
code3
<p>hello ernie</p>
<p>hello ben</p>
<p>hello mark</p>
```

Is there a way to keep the comments as they were (code1) and still insert all comments containing 'hello' after the comments.  Like

How it should look like.

```
<p>hello ernie</p>
<p>this is mark</p>
<p>hello ben</p>
<p>this is ernie</p>
<p>hello mark</p>
<p>this is ben</p>
```

```
<p>hello ernie</p>
<p>hello ben</p>
<p>hello mark</p>
```

Any hint or help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to create a copy then move only those copies, like this:

```
$("p:contains('hello')").clone().insertAfter("#comments");
```

Also [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) takes a selector directly, so no need to wrap it here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.clone()` like so:

```
$("p:contains('hello')").clone().insertAfter($("#comments"));
```